# Video plays upside down only in VLC media player

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player, rotate, windows-movie-maker

I seem to have an issue that is exactly the opposite of that of many other users with upside down video's.

The usual problem is that video players like Windows media player, quicktime or others play a video upside down. The answer to that issue is to use VLC media player to rotate the image. Or to use Windows Movie maker to rotate and save as a new movie.

However, my problem is 'upside down' so to speak.
I am already using VLC media player as my default player.
When I opened a movie today from my wife's phone in VLC, it played upside down.
So I started looking and found the answer to the problem above. Only... all the solutions I found didn't work for me, because they (Win Movie Maker, www.rotatemyvideo.net) all showed my video upright already. There was nothing to rotate. Windows media player also showed my video upright.

Only VLC doesn't seem to read the orientation correctly. I really like VLC for many reasons and do not want to change players... so does anyone have an idea on what I could do about this? Why can't vlc read the orientation of the video correctly?

The phone used to make the video's is a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini running on Android 4.4.4 with default camera app version 3.0

Comment: Have you tried taking another video with the phone and see if it does the same exact thing?

Comment: you could try looking at rotational metadata and if there then removing it https://superuser.com/questions/1579887/is-there-a-way-to-choose-whether-or-not-to-obey-rotational-metadata

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same problem.

It's a misconfiguration of the VLC settings.

Go to Tools > Effects & Filters > Video Effects > Geometry

What likely happened is that it accidentally was set to Transform > Rotate 180 degrees.  To correct, uncheck the Transform button

https://features.en.softonic.com/how-to-rotate-a-video-with-vlc

Comment: I don't know who had downvoted this; the solution was exactly right for me. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Just had the same error, was looking everywhere in VLC for a solution without luck :-)