# Does WMP or VLC have a way to choose whether or not to obey rotational metadata?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player, metadata

Does WMP or VLC have an option to choose whether or not to obey rotational metadata?

For example, here is a video http://ge.tt/78hJIb63    4 seconds , 10MB

I recorded it with my mobile phone positioned upright. And i'm recording a cordless (phone) handset resting upright against the side of a sofa.

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads>mediainfo VID_20200822_172736580.mp4
General
Complete name                            : VID_20200822_172736580.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
.....
Rotation                                 : 90°
...


C:\BLAH>
```

(ffmpeg -i on that video also shows that there is the rotational metadata there)

(that rotational metadata as shown by mediainfo, is an instruction or suggestion to video players to rotate it 90 degrees clockwise. The mobile phone recorded it such that it needs to be rotated 90 degrees clockwise to show right / be upright!)   (So my phone encodes it with an incorrect rotation and uses rotational metadata to adjust!)

Some video players ignore rotational metadata, and some pay attention to it.

Here is how it plays in Windows Media Player 2009 / Windows Media Player in Windows 7.

[image]

Here is how it plays in VLC

[image]

Here is how it plays in both, if I remove rotational metadata.

`ffmpeg -i VID_20200822_172736580.mp4  -metadata:s:v rotate="0" -c copy video_with_rotational_metadata_removed.mp4`

In Windows Media Player 2009 / WMP on win7

[image]

In VLC

[image]

So clearly with WMP 2009 / WMP on Win7, it makes no difference, so WMP-2009-win7 ignores rotational metadata.

And with VLC it makes a difference, so VLC obeys rotational metadata.

Note- WMP 2013 / WMP on Win10 , obeys rotational metadata.

Is there any way, in WMP or VLC or alternative video player , to choose whether or not to obey rotational metadata? VLC does have a transform feature but that's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: It's not possible to disable auto-rotation in VLC but you can override it - Preferences > Advanced > Video > Filters > Rotate and pick the rotation angle you want.

Comment: @DavidPostill see where I said, " VLC does have a transform feature but that's not what i'm looking for."   Also, is there any video player you know that has the option I mention?

Comment: No, I don't use any other video players.

Comment: @DavidPostill ok so the question stands. "Is there a way to choose whether or not to obey rotational metadata?" (clearly not in VLC and WMP).

Comment: I'm sure you are aware that asking for software recommendations is off topic. Just because you didn't get an answer on software recs doesn't mean you can ask here instead.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well the question I asked here didn't ask for what software would. I just asked How to do it.  The question  on software recommendations months back, was different, it asked what software would do it.

Comment: Your question starts with "Is there a media/video player that has an option to choose whether or not to obey rotational metadata?" ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I just amended my question to Does WMP or VLC have an option..

Comment: @DavidPostill How did my question get closed suddenly with seemingly no votes to close it?

Comment: I closed it as off topic and reopened after your edit. I've already told you VLC can't do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC or WMP can't.

(I see you used ffmpeg to remove rotational metadata, good that it can do that, and coincidentally, also, usefully, ffplay can choose whether or not to obey rotational metadata, with the -noautorotate and -autorotate options that take no parameters are are about whether or not to obey rotational metadata). So e.g. `ffplay blah.mp4 -noautorotate` or `ffplay blah.mp4 -autorotate`(default)

Comment: october 2015 version of MPC doesn't obey rotational metadata, but april 2022 version does obey it.  Still no option to choose  https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/issues/1739   Also a slight workaround is alt+3 on the number pad can rotate 90 degrees repeatedly.